# When trying to access the internet chrome is showing"google.com redirected you too many times" and throwing error"ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Whenever I am trying to access any website in any browser I am getting the error

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
>   google.com redirected you too many times.

I tried to clear the cache, cookies,reset the setting in chrome, delete browser history, turning off the hardware acceleration, tried to create a new profile but nothing is working also I deleted all the extensions and uninstalled and reinstalled chrome. Even tor is not responding what should I do guys please help me I am not able to study and my exams are nearing.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with writing code, or is this just a question about Chrome? This site is for programming questions.

Answer (score -2):

Outdated date or time settings might be another reason for **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

Chrome error.

Follow these steps to set proper date/time on your PC:

1. Click Win+R keys to open Run dialog.
2. Type control in the Run box and click OK.
3. Once you end up on Control Panel, choose Date and Time option.
4. Open Internet Time tab and click Change settings button.
5. In the newly appeared window, mark the checkbox next to Synchronize with an Internet time server option and select time server.
6. Click Update now button and then OK.

Try accessing the website again. Hopefully, this has helped to get rid of the Chrome redirect error.

Comment: I did try this too but again the same problem is recurring

Comment: Post your problem to a google chrome inclined forum.